# Detecting mouse movement continuously JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, mouseevent

I am developing a 3D engine on an html-canvas in JS and want to be able to handle mouse movements for camera movement. I want it to be able to track infinintly in every direction. I have tried to use `event.client(X/Y)`  to record the movement, but when the cursor comes to the end of the window or screen, the cursor can't move further, thus I can't look further in that direction. Is there a way to fix this without the use of libraries? Examples of it working are for example Krunker.io where you can move your crosshair around is space endlessly. (I think it is made using three js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Pointer-lock API which let's me lock the cursor and record the movement and used `event.movementX/Y` instead of `event.clientX/Y`. This makes you not run out of "screen real estate" and can rotate continuously.